# Client only connecting after restarting mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am debugging my python written flask application (using flask_mqtt) I just deployed on a raspberry pi zero wh. On my linux machine (notebook) everything works like a charm, however, on the raspberry pi I discovered that the MQTT client does not acknowledge that it connects to the mosquitto broker although the MQTT log states

```
1589448206: New client connected from ::1 as 15ae66e3-7fc3-4739-a5f5-a0fe16e6ed28 (c1, k5, u'test').
1589448230: New connection from ::1 on port 1883.
```

I just discovered that the flask app does acknowledge its connection when I do

```
sudo service mosquitto restart
```

Does anyone what might cause this?

As I said I use flask_mqtt (https://github.com/stlehmann/Flask-MQTT) and the follwing callbacks:

```
def subscribe_topics():
for topic in packet_manager.packets.keys():
    mqtt.subscribe(topic)

@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print(" * Connected to MQTT Broker successfully")
    subscribe_topics()
```

and the follwing MQTT settings

```
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = "webserver"
MQTT_BROKER_URL = 'localhost'
MQTT_BROKER_PORT = 1883
MQTT_USERNAME = 'test'
MQTT_PASSWORD = 'test'
MQTT_KEEPALIVE = 5
MQTT_TLS_ENABLED = False
```

The print + subscription is only executed after restarting the mosquitto service

Comment: Please do NOT cross post the same question to multiple sites (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794148/mqtt-client-only-connecting-after-restarting-broker)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asked, and updated on Stack Overflow